# How can I convert List of LinkedHashMap to List of Custom Object using Java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

How can we convert List<LinkedHashMap> in to List of Custom Object (List<Employee>) using Java 8 Streams.

Example : List<LinkedHashMap>

Here name and designation both are LinkedHashmap key. if you copy below snippet in IDE you can have better understand of this List<LinkedHashMap>.

```
List<LinkedHashMap> list = new ArrayList<>();
LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedHashMap1 = new LinkedHashMap<>((Map.of("name","David", "designation","Senior Software Engineer")));
LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedHashMap2 = new LinkedHashMap<>((Map.of("name","Alex", "designation","Software Engineer")));
LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedHashMap3 = new LinkedHashMap<>((Map.of("name","Jessi","designation","Lead")));
LinkedHashMap<String, String> linkedHashMap4 = new LinkedHashMap<>((Map.of("name","Martin","designation","Manager")));

list.add(linkedHashMap1);
list.add(linkedHashMap2);
list.add(linkedHashMap3);
list.add(linkedHashMap4);
System.out.println(list);
```

Need to convert above List<LinkedHashmap> to List<Employee> Where Employee class has below two fields :

```
Class Employee {
String name;
String designation;
}
```

Expected output :

```
[Employee(name = David, designation = Senior Software Engineer), 
Employee(name = Alex, designation = Software Engineer), 
Employee(name = Jessi, designation = Lead),
Employee(name = Martin, designation = Manager)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a stream over the source list. And transform every *map* in the list into an instance of `Employee` using the values mapped to the keys `"name"` and `"designation"`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Map<String, String>> source = List.of(
            Map.of("name","David", "designation","Senior Software Engineer"),
            Map.of("name","Alex", "designation","Software Engineer"),
            Map.of("name","Jessi","designation","Lead"),
            Map.of("name","Martin","designation","Manager"));

    List<Employee> result = source.stream()
            .map(map -> new Employee(map.get("name"), map.get("designation")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

**Output**

```
Employee{name='David', designation='Senior Software Engineer'}
Employee{name='Alex', designation='Software Engineer'}
Employee{name='Jessi', designation='Lead'}
Employee{name='Martin', designation='Manager'}
```

**Note:**

- It's not a good practice to store an *object* as a *map*. In your example, nothing can save you from typo, and you will get `null` instead of an attribute value.
- Don't drop the generic information.

Answer (score 0):

Using streams you can use the code below providing that your Employe class has a constructor with this signature: public Employe(String name, String designation).

```
List<Employe> customList= list.stream()
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
    .map(entry -> new Employe(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .toList();
```

Comment: Yes I have constructor and tried above solution but not able to convert to custom Employe List..

Comment: well you changed the question, I guess the answer has to change